# Avoid classpath scanning for Spring Configuration classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

Using Spring, it is possible to use Classes annotated with @Configuration to configure various aspects of an application. These Configuration classes could be imported directly or collected using classpath scanning.

It seems to me that classpath scanning has several drawbacks for Configuration Classes in particular.
 One major drawback is that for multi-projects (subprojects in gradle or maven), the IDE is prone not to agree with the build system on what goes onto the classpath when.

In particular in my current case, gradle will isolate classpath test resources (files in src/main/test) for each subproject, meaning a test in one subproject will not by classpath scanning find Spring classes from other subproject tests (unless specifying this). IntelliJ (13.1.4) however does not make this isolation, causing test results to be different in gradle and IntelliJ. This can re-occur anytime (new intelliJ or Eclipse versions), and while a bug like any other, this is a major annoyance.

The other problem we faced is that Spring provides a toolkit for running tests, such as

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class FooTest {...}
```

Or

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class FooTest {...}
```

Since these Test classes end up on the classpath, they can also slyly influence other tests by being detected and used as Spring Configurations.

So is it generally bad to scan the classpath for configurations, or are we missing some obvious mitigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now, I commonly use classpath scanning sparingly, following these rules:

- A configuration should only scan packages in the same module
- A configuratino should only scan in it's own or a subpackage

Else it seems much better to use @Import targetting another Configuration. it makes the intention and dependency much more explicit, and helps avoiding classpath issues.